# Create table and setting identity seed using sp_executesql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need help creating a table using the 'sp_executesql' command in sql server and setting the seed with a variable. I get the seed I want and store it in @theSeed

```
DECLARE @theSeed int
SELECT @theSeed = (MAX([Id]) + 1) FROM [Person]
```

then i want to create the table and use this seed as the identity seed in the new table

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'CREATE TABLE [NewPerson] (
    [PersonId] [int] IDENTITY(5000 , 1) NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PersonId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]'
GO
```

I need to replace the 5000 with the value in @theSeed. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DBCC CHECKIDENT` command for this as:

```
--command to check the current identity value
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('NewPerson')

-- create table and reseed value with @theSeed variable:
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('NewPerson', RESEED, @theSeed)
```

or you can write the dynamic query as:

```
DECLARE @theSeed int
SELECT @theSeed = (MAX([Id]) + 1) FROM [Person]

declare @sql nvarchar(4000)
set @sql = 'CREATE TABLE [NewPerson] (
    [PersonId] [int] IDENTITY(' + cast(@theSeed as varchar) + ', 1) NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PersonId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]'


EXEC sp_executesql @sql
GO

--command to check the current identity value
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('NewPerson', NORESEED)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    DECLARE @theSeed int
    SELECT @theSeed = (MAX([Id]) + 1) FROM [Person]
declare @sql varchar(1000) = 'CREATE TABLE [NewPerson] (
        [PersonId] [int] IDENTITY(' + @theSeed + ', 1) NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [PersonId] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]'
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
    GO
```

Comment: You need to construct the string on a separate line - you can't pass *expressions* in an `EXEC` call - you can either pass string literals or parameters, but you can't pass the result of a set of `+` operations.

Comment: complains about incorrect syntax, think the int needs to be cast, thanks for the tip though